# How is a sample from a Bernoulli distribution different from a binomial distribution?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution

The binomial distribution can be interpreted as $n$ independent and identically Bernoulli "trials". If $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ is a sample from a Bernoulli distribution, how is that different from a binomial distribution?

Answer (score 5):

A binomial distribution occurs if you add them: $Y = X_1 + \ldots + X_n$.  If you just leave them as is, they are a sample from a Bernoulli distribution.